# javascript innerhtml return value

Tags: javascript, html, dom, innerhtml

I am having trouble to understand this.
I have this bit code:

```
document.getElementById("widget-container-1").innerHTML="<div class='title'>Select town: "+
         "<select id='drop'>"+
         "<option name='Auckland' value='Auckland'>Auckland</option>"+
         "<option name='Christchurch' value='Christchurch'>Christchurch</option>"+
         "<option name='Dunedin' value='Dunedin'>Dunedin</option>"+
         "<option>Hamilton</option>"+
         "<option>Tauranga</option>"+
         "<option>Wellington</option>"+
         "</select><br />"+      
         "<button id='update' name='update' onClick=\"this, _refreshWeatherDisplay(test);'\">update</button></div>"+
         "<div class='monitor'>Sort by"+
         "<input id='radio' name='input' type='radio' value='0' >town"+
         "<input id='radio' name='input' type='radio' value='1' >max temp"+
         "<div class='section'>test</div></div>";        

        select = document.getElementById("drop");
         select.onchange = function(){
            _checkNewTown(this.options[this.selectedIndex].text);
         };
```

I want to get the data and perform another function:

```
var _checkNewTown =  function(ntown){
    alert(this.selectedIndex);
}
```

But, in the -checkNewTown function is keep return indefined.
And the button is not working when I try to alert it.

```
var _refreshWeatherDisplay = function(weather_info){
 alert("test");
}
```

I know is could be simple, but I have no clue what I am doing wrong
If anyone could help me will be very appreciatted.

Comment: Either I don't get it, or you can just call another function with: `callFunction(data);`

Comment: What is the problem? Did you try putting `_checkNewTown(this.options[this.selectedIndex].text);` in the onchange function?

Comment: Note that with select elements, the change event on varies between browsers. E.g. the control may need to lose focus in some browsers but not others before a change event is dispatched. If navigating by cursor keys, IE will dispatch a change event each time the cursor key is pressed to highlight a new option.

Comment: Hi all, thanks for reply, I am new for javascript, sorry my question a little bit incomplete. I am trying to pass the value from select option to new function _checkNewTown function, I was using an alert to test it - alert(this.selectedIndex), but the alert is returning indefined data, here I am having trouble to pick the data from there.

Comment: I updated the code for my question, if anyone could help me, I really appreciate it. thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were quite a few syntax errors in your code, look into the console for your browser in-order to track these errors down (F12 for IE9 and Chrome, Ctrl+Shift+J in Firefox). This code works fine on my end:

```
document.getElementById("widget-container-1").innerHTML = "<div class='title'>Select town: "+
    "<select id='drop'>"+
    "<option name='Auckland' value='Auckland'>Auckland</option>"+
    "<option name='Christchurch' value='Christchurch'>Christchurch</option>"+
    "<option name='Dunedin' value='Dunedin'>Dunedin</option>"+
    "<option>Hamilton</option>"+
    "<option>Tauranga</option>"+
    "<option>Wellington</option>"+
    "</select><br />"+      
    "<button id='update' name='update' onClick=\"_refreshWeatherDisplay('test');\">update</button></div>"+
    "<div class='monitor'>Sort by"+
    "<input id='radio' name='input' type='radio' value='0' >town"+
    "<input id='radio' name='input' type='radio' value='1' >max temp"+
    "<div class='section'>test</div></div>";        
select = document.getElementById("drop");
select.onchange = function(){
    _checkNewTown(select.options[select.selectedIndex].value);
};
```

And your functions:

```
var _checkNewTown =  function(ntown){
    alert(ntown);
};
var _refreshWeatherDisplay = function(weather_info){
    alert("test");
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, yes, there are few errors, because my code are incomplete, I am trying to learn javascript and decide to create a weather widget, but not found many thing out there, everything is already done, I would like to learn from begin. Hope find tutorial or something to help me. thanks